# when bike kept inside, brake/ lever goes extremely stiff

Tags: brakes, brake-levers

so, I've been through a lot of fiddling with my brake levers, giving them a small clean out and bleed, but I've noticed now that when i keep my bike inside (on heated floor) the brake levers go stiff, and the pads pinch the rotors... I've had friends saying the piston swells up in the lever or 'too much fluid', but when i leave it outside, the brakes go back to perfect, perhaps the fluid, is there such thing as cheap fluid that expands perhaps? Shimano saint if it helps.

Comment: This appears similar to the gen 1 Guide issue where the levers would seize when left in the sun. The fix was to pour cold water on them. It was a seal on or around the lever piston that caused the issue. SRAM warrantied a lot of them so I'm not sure if a fix was found. Can you get your's replaced under warranty?

Comment: Mineral oil does expand when heated, but only marginally. Have you tried to remove a small amount of fluid while the levers are sticking and does it make a difference? Even just removing the reservoir plug while the brake is warm and sticking may allow enough oil to escape.

Comment: Because it's not a known fault with Saints, it could easily be too much oil.

Comment: Do you push the pistons back while bleeding?  A brake piston block helps immensely.

Comment: Do the brakes go stiff while riding? If its too much fluid and heat related, then I would expect them to play up when being ridden hard.

Comment: @mattnz not if it's heat at the levers (or indeed anywhere away from the calipers).  The path the heat would have to take is just too long and narrow

Comment: What fluid did you use? Is there any known time any other oil or grease might have been come into contact with the lever or caliper?

Comment: @Chris - The expanding fluid in the calipers would increase the pressure evenly in the entire system.  The heat form the calipers is much higher than the difference in ambient temperatures (presuming not storing at something like -30degrees outside), so I am presuming a similar amount of total fluid expansion. Therefore if heated calipers do not cause the problem, the problem is unlikely to be expanding fluid.

Comment: @mattnz you're right, the pressure would increase throughout the line from hot calipers, though not necessarily in the reservoir with the lever squeezed.

Comment: ...You also heat a tiny amount of fluid in the caliper body and bottom of the hose compared to the whole length of hose+master cylinder+reservoir so you'd need to consider the same ratio in temperature change as in heated volumes.  If the volume heated by braking is 5x less than by warming the bike, the same pressure change will be caused by 5x higher temperature: 0°C ambient, 20°C room temp, and 100°C caliper temp are reasonable values (in this hemisphere where it's currently winter) and 5x is IMO a reasonable guess for the volume ratio